# Error building project using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I am getting the error:

```
error loading package '': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '//tensorflow/tensorflow:workspace.bzl': BUILD file not found on package path.
```

Any time I try to run bazel for a project using tensorflow.
I copied the workspace file from https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/WORKSPACE

And here is my version of the workspace file:

```
workspace(name = "tf_sketch_rec")

local_repository(
  name = "tf_graph_build",
  path = __workspace_dir__ + "/src/main/python",
)

local_repository(
  name = "tf_graph_run",
  path = __workspace_dir__ + "/src/main/java",
)

load('//tensorflow/tensorflow:workspace.bzl', 'tf_workspace')
tf_workspace("tensorflow/", "@tf")

# Specify the minimum required Bazel version.
load("@tf//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "check_version")
check_version("0.2.0")

# ===== gRPC dependencies =====

bind(
    name = "libssl",
    actual = "@boringssl_git//:ssl",
)

git_repository(
    name = "boringssl_git",
    commit = "436432d849b83ab90f18773e4ae1c7a8f148f48d",
    init_submodules = True,
    remote = "https://github.com/mdsteele/boringssl-bazel.git",
)

bind(
    name = "zlib",
    actual = "@zlib_archive//:zlib",
)

new_http_archive(
    name = "zlib_archive",
    build_file = "zlib.BUILD",
    sha256 = "879d73d8cd4d155f31c1f04838ecd567d34bebda780156f0e82a20721b3973d5",
    strip_prefix = "zlib-1.2.8",
    url = "http://zlib.net/zlib128.zip",
)
```

I do have tensorflow installed and python runs the files that it can that do not require bazel to be installed.

Comment: this is more related on how bazel works. the error is telling you that is trying to find the bazel file in the subidrectory `//tensorflow/tensorflow:workspace.bzl` so you need copy that file and change many things... it is easier to add your directory to the tensorflow workspace. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to add tensorflow to a decently sized project that mixes java and python.
is there a way to do this without needing to add my files to the tensor flow workspace?
my main goal is to export the graph in python and then run it in java and cpp.